# How can you run OpenVPN client inside a docker container?

Tags: networking, docker, openvpn, ipv6

I want to run a OpenVPN client inside a docker container. I tried as following in an ad-hoc test:

```
docker run -it --rm --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --device /dev/net/tun -v $PWD:$PWD ubuntu bash

in the container:

apt-get update && apt-get install -y openvpn
openvpn --config myconfig.ovpn
```

(I add the volume mount `-v $PWD:$PWD` to get my OpenVPN configurations into the container, for the sake of this ad-hoc test.)

Then I get suddenly in the logging:

```
Fri Jul 12 17:19:37 2019 /sbin/ip -6 addr add <ip>/64 dev tun0
RTNETLINK answers: Permission denied
Fri Jul 12 17:19:37 2019 Linux ip -6 addr add failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Fri Jul 12 17:19:37 2019 Exiting due to fatal error
```

It looks like there are some issues with IPv6, but I am not sure how to continue now.

Note that if I repeat the above with `--net=host` added to `docker run`, everything works. But that is not what I really wanted. I would like to have the OpenVPN client running isolated in the container.

For what it is worth, I don't need IPv6. All the hosts reachable in the VPN network are reachable via IPv4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it working. It looks like I have to enable IPv6 manually:

```
docker run -it --rm --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --device /dev/net/tun \
           --sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0 -v $PWD:$PWD \
           ubuntu bash
```